# Cannot connect to slushpool with bfgminer

Tags: miner-configuration, ubuntu, bfgminer, slush

I am a complete newbie and just want to see how mining works in principle. No profit required. I have created an account on slushpool and have username and password. Then I go to my Ubuntu machine (a desktop, with GPU, no ASICs or something) and ran

```
bfgminer -o stratum+tcp://stratum.slushpool.com:3333 -u myusername -p mypassword
```

It started to print in cycles

```
 [2020-11-13 10:17:47] Waiting for devices; press 'M+' to add, or 'Q' to quit
 [2020-11-13 10:17:47] Probing for an alive pool
 [2020-11-13 10:17:48] pool 0 JSON stratum auth failed: [
   -1,
   "Internal Server Error",
   null
]
 [2020-11-13 10:17:48] No servers were found that could be used to get work from.
 [2020-11-13 10:17:48] Please check the details from the list below of the servers you have input
 [2020-11-13 10:17:48] Most likely you have input the wrong URL, forgotten to add a port, or have not set up workers
 [2020-11-13 10:17:48] Pool: 0  URL: stratum+tcp://stratum.slushpool.com:3333  User: myusername Password: mypassword
 [2020-11-13 10:17:48] Press any key to exit, or BFGMiner will try again in 15s.
 [2020-11-13 10:18:04] No servers were found that could be used to get work from.
 [2020-11-13 10:18:04] Please check the details from the list below of the servers you have input
 [2020-11-13 10:18:04] Most likely you have input the wrong URL, forgotten to add a port, or have not set up workers
 [2020-11-13 10:18:04] Pool: 0  URL: stratum+tcp://stratum.slushpool.com:3333  User: myusername  Password: mypassword
```

Why? What is happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looking at the error message it seems that you have used the incorrect URL for server. Try using other URLs mentioned here and see if you get the same error: https://help.slushpool.com/en/support/solutions/articles/77000422800-bitcoin-mining-setup-on-slush-pool-

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to slushpool with bfgminer.
follow steps if it works to you .

```
sudo bfgminer
```

then enter url

```
stratum+tcp://stratum.slushpool.com:3333
```

then it will ask username with worker

```
username.worker
```

then password

thats it .